# string.replace is not working for quotes

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have a string like

```
mukesh "salaria" engineer
```

how do i replace " with blank

like i want output as

```
mukesh salaria engineer
```

I already tried,

```
 str.replace("\"",string.empty);
```

but it doesn't working for me.

Comment: this will work for you hope you understand what `\"` means 
`var strrep = "mukesh \"salaria\" engineer";`
`strrep = strrep.Replace("\"", "");`

Answer (score 2):

It works but must type this: `str = str.replace(...)`

Comment: it's not working too..

Comment: What is the result? Try `str = str.replace("\"", "");`

Comment: The above answer definitely works. So `Console.WriteLine("mukesh \"salaria\" engineer".Replace("\"", ""));` prints `mukesh salaria engineer`.

Comment: There is not escape character like \"salaria\". its "salaria"

Comment: \" are because quote is part of string.

Comment: also fix your syntax `str = str.Replace(...)` pay attention to case sensitivity

Comment: I used lowercase replace because that was in the question and was not sure whether it is C# or Java.

Comment: case is not problem here..i am typing Replace()

Answer (score 1):

You must use the `Replace` method and get the string back from it. Your code must be:

```
str = str.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
```

[msdn :](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified string in the current instance are replaced with another specified string.

Answer (score 1):

string.Replace is a pure method(no side-effects). If you do not assign `str.replace("\"",string.empty);` to anything, then that statement does not make any change in the state of your object(in other words writing that line of code is equal to not writing it at all.).

Use `str = str.Replace(...);`

Comment: it gives error "Invalid expression term"

Comment: `-1`why do you think I need to click something I think that you do not understand what I was getting at in C# `str=str.replace()` will not compile because there is no method name `replace()` it's named `Replace();`

Comment: @DJKRAZE it is just a copy-paste from the question.

Comment: doesn't matter.. trust me there are plenty of beginners that would copy and paste literally and try to run it and it would give the good old red squiggly lines and they would probably not know to change the lowercase `r` to `R` because there are a lot of individuals that visit here that neglect to debug so I don't agree with your comment

Comment: LOL how can this receive an upvote when you just stated that it doesn't work ..LOL `it gives error "Invalid expression term"`

Comment: @DJKRAZE I agree with your comment about beginners. But as you see in the answer, my suggestion is `Use str = str.Replace(...);`. `R` is uppercase.

Comment: @DJKRAZE Besides, that lower-case, upper-case issue shouldnt be a reason for downvote. By the way, I did not state that it does not work.

Comment: I didn't downvote you I was trying to respond to your comment about clicking on a link

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
str.Replace('\"',' ');
```

Comment: This is wrong because extra space will be inserted in the place of quote.

Comment: no its not working too..:(